# Terraform doesn't have a Ground Truth resource. How do I create my own resource?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

As far as I can tell, terraform doesn't have any support for [Sagemaker Ground Truth](https://aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/groundtruth/). However AWS CLI [does support it](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sagemaker/create-labeling-job.html).

I don't want to create a whole new provider as a plugin, especially as this falls under aws.

How do I create my own resource within the existing aws provider?

Comment: If you can confirm that API endpoint is not covered by the provider, then you can PR the resource to the provider to cover the endpoint. The provider's issue tracker, roadmap, and current PRs would probably be a good first step here.

Comment: While that is the ideal solution, note that some of the most heavily-upvoted issues and PRs on the AWS provider repo haven't been merged after 12+ months of the community begging for it. It's good to get the issue started, but don't expect it to be available within the next 6 - 12 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options here (and in general, when something isn't supported by the Terraform AWS provider).

1. If the resource in question is supported by CloudFormation, you can use the [aws_cloudformation_stack](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cloudformation_stack) Terraform resource to create a custom CloudFormation stack that creates and tracks the state of the resource. [Here's](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_SageMaker.html) the CloudFormation documentation for SageMaker; see if you can find the resource you want in there anywhere.
2. If it's only supported by the CLI (not by CloudFormation), you can use the CLI in your Terraform configuration. [This is the module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Invicton-Labs/shell-resource/external/latest) I like to use for doing CLI work in Terraform. The downside is that you must have the AWS CLI installed on whatever machine you're doing the `terraform apply` on.